# Is it possible to configure default email filters for users?

Tags: windows, email, outlook, filter, defaults

We have about 500 students and 50 personel. We use Outlook email.

Students and personel have different domains. Students' domain contains "edu." but personels domain doesn't.

Is it possible to configure default email filters for personel so that all student email goes to a different folder than all the other email?

We do not want all personel to create their own filters. We want them to have filters without any of their own actions.

Comment: However well intentioned, imposing a centrally managed mail inbox rules and associated folder structure and ensuring that certain mail does not arrive in your staffs INBOX will result in (some) confusion.  Also consider what happens when students don't use their .edu account to send messages, but rather their personal Gmail or Hotmail account and those messages do arrive in the normal INBOX. -Regardless of the (im)possibility of doing what you ask, consider what problem you're solving by not allowing your staff their own inbox rules, but on the other hand enforcing your own.

Comment: Staff has full rights to do everything they like with their email filters, but I doubt many of them know what an email filter is. Problem atm is that we have two different accounts. Emails are sorted in "different places" as it is. New thing would be that we would only have one account and still have student email in "different place", just technically in a different way. We just dont want student email mixed with our normal email *and* we do not want two different accounts.